# add counter start from zero in Java script table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code it's working correctly. but it's starting first row with number one. Any one has idea how start from zero . can any one help me with that?
thanks

```
<script>

var tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
    var table = tables[tables.length - 1];
    var rows = table.rows;
    for(var i = 0, td; i < rows.length; i++){
        td = document.createElement('td');
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i + 1));
        rows[i].insertBefore(td, rows[i].firstChild);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `document.createTextNode(i + 1)`  - `document.createTextNode(i)`?

```js
var tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
    var table = tables[tables.length - 1];
    var rows = table.rows;
    for(var i = 0, td; i < rows.length; i++){
        td = document.createElement('td');
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i === 0 ? '#' : i));
        rows[i].insertBefore(td, rows[i].firstChild);
    }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
  <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it's work correctly and  could i change the zero number to # symbol  many thanks

Comment: you want to print `#` instead of zero only? You can do that by cheking against zero.

Comment: yes i want to print # instead of zero. could you make it simple for me i still new in coding .i appreciate that..

Comment: I have add conditional in code to print #  instead of zero